# Flutter web Share same websocket connection on multiple tabs

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

How to share same web-socket connection on multiple tabs in flutter web.

Suppose I have some named routes in different tabs:
myurl/main
myurl/profile
myurl/connection

How to share same web-socket connection between these tabs ?

Comment: Any update on this?